# How to refer to an unknown signer, in the parties section of an agreement

Tags: contract-law, digital-contract, adhesion-contracts

Have an agreement that will be signed by someone but we want to reuse the agreement and not edit each time to add the signers name.

My question is how can I refer to the signer at the top of the agreement, without editing the agreement to show their name each time?

Answer (score 4):

One could replace:

> The following agreement constitutes the relationship and commitments between Our Company LLC (Agency) and (Client).

With

> The following agreement constitutes the relationship and commitments between Our Company LLC, referred to in this agreement as "the Agency", and the other party, specifically identified in the signature section, and refereed to in this agreement as "the Client" or "You".